# Direct3D11 drawing of a cube of cubes

Tags: c, direct3d11

I have this:

[image]

My code is at:

[http://codepad.org/TIETN4Ua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGMu7.jpg)

I have no idea how to do something like this:

[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: StackOverflow is not a freelance programming service, you have to try it by yourself and post your issues here with sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Texture and surface properties, light source(s), reflectivity and so on. Just keep going, step by step achievement is the way to go. Thankfully the desired image has no shadow casting ;)

Comment: You might want to check out the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11 tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Before you draw that many objects, take a look at indexed drawing.